# Trouble porting backtracking algorithm to cuda kernel

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I have been trying to optimize my image processing library with `numba.cuda`, mostly successfully.
However, the following backtracking function has been causing me quite a headache.

The function receives a `numpy.ndarray` of type `uint8` and shape `(r, c, 3)` representing an image.
It calculates an energy map for the image of type `float32` and shape `(r,c)`.
It then backtracks through the energy map calculating a backtrack array and minimum energy array that the function then returns.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

FILTER_DU = np.stack([np.array([
    [1.0, 2.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [-1.0, -2.0, -1.0],
])] * 3, axis=2)
 
FILTER_DV = np.stack([np.array([
    [1.0, 0.0, -1.0],
    [2.0, 0.0, -2.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, -1.0],
])] * 3, axis=2)

@cuda.jit
def b_convolve(result, img):
    filter_du = cuda.const.array_like(FILTER_DU)
    filter_dv = cuda.const.array_like(FILTER_DV)
    
    # 2D coords of the current thread
    i, j = cuda.grid(2) 
    
    # Ignore thread if coords are outside image
    img_x, img_y, img_z = img.shape
    if (i >= img_x) or (j >= img_y):
        return
    
    delta_x = filter_du.shape[0] // 2 
    delta_y = filter_du.shape[1] // 2
    #delta_z = filter_du.shape[1] // 2 <- not needed since 3rd dim is always 3 long (R,G,B)
    
    # The result at coordinates (i, j) is equal to 
    # abs(sum_{k,l,m} filter_du[k, l, m] * img[i-k+delta_x, j-l+delta_y, 1-delta_z]) +
    # abs(sum_{k,l,m} filter_dv[k, l, m] * img[i-k+delta_x, j-l+delta_y, 1-delta_z])
    # with k, l and m going through the whole mask array
    s1=0
    s2=0
    for k in range(filter_du.shape[0]):
        for l in range(filter_du.shape[1]):
            i_k = i - k + delta_x
            j_l = j - l + delta_y
            # Check if (i_k, j_k) coordinates are inside the image: 
            if (0 <= i_k < img_x) and (0 <= j_l < img_y):
                s1 += filter_du[k, l, 0] * img[i_k, j_l, 1]
                s1 += filter_du[k, l, 1] * img[i_k, j_l, 0]
                s1 += filter_du[k, l, 2] * img[i_k, j_l, -1]
                
                s2 += filter_dv[k, l, 0] * img[i_k, j_l, 1]
                s2 += filter_dv[k, l, 1] * img[i_k, j_l, 0]
                s2 += filter_dv[k, l, 2] * img[i_k, j_l, -1]
    result[i, j] = abs(s1)+abs(s2)

def calc_energy(img):
    img = np.ascontiguousarray(img.astype('float32'))
    
    energy_map = np.empty(img.shape[:2]).astype('float32')
    
    blockdim = (32,32)
    griddim = (img.shape[0] // blockdim[0] + 1, img.shape[1] // blockdim[1] + 1)
    
    b_convolve[griddim, blockdim](energy_map, img)
    
    return energy_map

def create_backtrack(img):
    r, c, _ = img.shape
    energy_map = calc_energy(img)
 
    M = energy_map.copy()
    backtrack = np.zeros_like(M, dtype=np.int)
 
    for i in range(1, r):
        for j in range(0, c):
            # Handle the left edge of the image, to ensure we don't index a -1
            if j == 0:
                idx = np.argmin(M[i-1, j:j + 2])
                backtrack[i, j] = idx + j
                min_energy = M[i-1, idx + j]
            else:
                idx = np.argmin(M[i - 1, j - 1:j + 2])
                backtrack[i, j] = idx + j - 1
                min_energy = M[i - 1, idx + j - 1]
 
            M[i, j] += min_energy
 
    return M, backtrack
```

Below is my attempt at porting this function over to a cuda kernel. Note `idx + j` is replaced with `idx` since `cuda_argmin` already accounts for `j` (or at least it should).

```py
@cuda.jit('int32(float32[:,:], int32, int32, int32)', device=True)
def cuda_argmin(M, i, j, k):
    min_val = M[i, j]
    min_ind = j
    for x in range(j+1, k):
        if M[i, x] < min_val:
            min_val = M[i, x]
            min_ind = x
    return min_ind

@cuda.jit('void(int32[:,:], float32[:,:])')
def cuda_backtrack(backtrack, M):
    i, j = cuda.grid(2)
    
    if i == 0:
        return
        
    min_energy = 0
    if j == 0:
        idx = cuda_argmin(M, i-1, j, j+2)
        backtrack[i, j] = idx
        min_energy = M[i-1, idx]
    else:
        idx = cuda_argmin(M, i-1, j-1, j+2)
        backtrack[i, j] = idx-1
        min_energy = M[i-1, idx-1]
    M[i, j] += min_energy

def create_backtrack(img):
    r, c, _ = img.shape
    energy_map = calc_energy(img)
    
    M = energy_map.copy()
    backtrack = np.zeros_like(M, dtype=np.int)
    
    blockdim = (32, 32)
    griddim = (r // blockdim[0] + 1, c // blockdim[1] + 1)
    cuda_backtrack[griddim, blockdim](backtrack, M)
    
    return M, backtrack
```

Looking at the output of the functions given a [4x4 image](https://pastebin.com/k0rUSnhv) we can see that the results aren't even close to matching.

```py
# Regular backtracking function
M = array([[1750., 1622., 1752., 1176.],
           [3364., 2982., 3124., 2538.],
           [5060., 4754., 4228., 4212.],
           [6278., 6528., 6354., 5866.]], dtype=float32)

backtrack = array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 3, 3],
                   [1, 1, 3, 3],
                   [1, 2, 3, 3]])
```

```py
# Cuda backtrack function
M = array([[4.2e-45, 2.9e-44, 3.1e-44, 3.2e-44],
           [3.6e-44, 1.5e-44, 1.7e-44, 2.0e-44],
           [2.2e-44, 2.8e-44, 2.8e-44, 2.9e-44],
           [3.2e-44, 3.8e-44, 4.2e-44, 4.3e-44]], dtype=float32)

backtrack = array([[ 0, -1,  2,  3],
                   [ 4,  0,  2,  2],
                   [ 2,  4,  4,  6],
                   [ 6,  9, 10, 11]])
```

I am clearly doing something wrong but I can't quite see where. How is it the outputs vary so much?

**Edit:** As per @talonmies suggestion I included the `calc_energy` function to the code so it's at least runnable as long as you have `numba` and `numpy` installed.

Comment: It would be much more helpful to provide a complete [MCVE] rather than code  nobody can run and analyze

Comment: You're absolutely correct @talonmies , thanks for pointing it out :). I have now included the calc_energy function so the code is at least runnable as long as numba and numpy is installed.

Comment: I am completely unfamiliar with whatever that backtrack kernel is trying to do, but it definitely contains a memory race, and it the underlying algorithm requires an specific execution order, it can't be implemented as you have done it in CUDA, because there is no predictable execution order on the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 3 problems in your code, the first of which has already been pointed out:

1. You are using `M` as both an input and an output.  The output values of `M` depend on other values of `M`.  Since CUDA provides no statements about the order of thread execution, assigning a CUDA thread to every output value of `M` will generally not give the same results as your serial version.   However we can observe that the `M` values for a given row (`i`) depend only on the `M` values of the previous row (`i-1`). This means we can parallelize across a row, but not across a column (at least not easily).
2. In the creation of your `backtrack` array, you appear to be handling the left edge properly (`j==0`) but not the right edge properly (`j==c-1`).  This coding error will result in a numerical difference between the cuda output and the numpy output.
3. Your two `argmin` functions do not return the same thing, and you have not accounted for this correctly. The numpy argmin returns 0, 1, or 2. When you add `j-1` to that you get `j-1`, `j`, or `j+1` as possible values for the `backtrack` entry.  Your cuda argmin function returns `j-1`, `j`, or `j+1`. When you subtract 1, those values don't match numpy.

As suggested, we can fix the first problem by parallelizing across a row.  However each row must be fully computed before we can go on to computing the next row.  To use this effectively, we need a synchronization point across all CUDA threads.  CUDA provides this at the block level, but the provision for this capability in CUDA at the grid level is not exposed via numba CUDA.

The following code has enough of the above items addressed so that at least the output from the two different methods matches.    However the remaining issues are related to item 1.  This approach only uses a single threadblock so that we can take advantage of per-row synchronization of all threads.  That's not a good final solution for performance on a GPU.  If you had multiple sets of these operations to do, then you could do those in parallel by assigning one image processing task per block, and get good performance that way.

```
$ cat t48.py
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

FILTER_DU = np.stack([np.array([
    [1.0, 2.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [-1.0, -2.0, -1.0],
])] * 3, axis=2)

FILTER_DV = np.stack([np.array([
    [1.0, 0.0, -1.0],
    [2.0, 0.0, -2.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, -1.0],
])] * 3, axis=2)

@cuda.jit
def b_convolve(result, img):
    filter_du = cuda.const.array_like(FILTER_DU)
    filter_dv = cuda.const.array_like(FILTER_DV)

    # 2D coords of the current thread
    i, j = cuda.grid(2)

    # Ignore thread if coords are outside image
    img_x, img_y, img_z = img.shape
    if (i >= img_x) or (j >= img_y):
        return

    delta_x = filter_du.shape[0] // 2
    delta_y = filter_du.shape[1] // 2
    #delta_z = filter_du.shape[1] // 2 <- not needed since 3rd dim is always 3 long (R,G,B)

    # The result at coordinates (i, j) is equal to
    # abs(sum_{k,l,m} filter_du[k, l, m] * img[i-k+delta_x, j-l+delta_y, 1-delta_z]) +
    # abs(sum_{k,l,m} filter_dv[k, l, m] * img[i-k+delta_x, j-l+delta_y, 1-delta_z])
    # with k, l and m going through the whole mask array
    s1=0
    s2=0
    for k in range(filter_du.shape[0]):
        for l in range(filter_du.shape[1]):
            i_k = i - k + delta_x
            j_l = j - l + delta_y
            # Check if (i_k, j_k) coordinates are inside the image:
            if (0 <= i_k < img_x) and (0 <= j_l < img_y):
                s1 += filter_du[k, l, 0] * img[i_k, j_l, 1]
                s1 += filter_du[k, l, 1] * img[i_k, j_l, 0]
                s1 += filter_du[k, l, 2] * img[i_k, j_l, -1]

                s2 += filter_dv[k, l, 0] * img[i_k, j_l, 1]
                s2 += filter_dv[k, l, 1] * img[i_k, j_l, 0]
                s2 += filter_dv[k, l, 2] * img[i_k, j_l, -1]
    result[i, j] = abs(s1)+abs(s2)

def calc_energy(img):
    img = np.ascontiguousarray(img.astype('float32'))

    energy_map = np.empty(img.shape[:2]).astype('float32')

    blockdim = (32,32)
    griddim = (img.shape[0] // blockdim[0] + 1, img.shape[1] // blockdim[1] + 1)

    b_convolve[griddim, blockdim](energy_map, img)

    return energy_map

def create_backtrack(img):
    r, c, _ = img.shape
    energy_map = calc_energy(img)
    print(energy_map)
    M = energy_map.copy()
    backtrack = np.zeros_like(M, dtype=np.int)

    for i in range(1, r):
        for j in range(0, c):
            # Handle the left edge of the image, to ensure we don't index a -1
            if j == 0:
                idx = np.argmin(M[i-1, j:j + 2])
                backtrack[i, j] = idx + j
                min_energy = M[i-1, idx + j]
            elif j == c-1:
                idx = np.argmin(M[i-1, j-1:j + 1])
                backtrack[i, j] = idx + j - 1
                min_energy = M[i-1, idx + j - 1]
            else:
                idx = np.argmin(M[i - 1, j - 1:j + 2])
                backtrack[i, j] = idx + j - 1
                min_energy = M[i - 1, idx + j - 1]

            M[i, j] += min_energy

    return M, backtrack

@cuda.jit('int32(float32[:,:], int32, int32, int32)', device=True)
def cuda_argmin(M, i, j, k):
    min_val = M[i, j]
    min_ind = j
    for x in range(j+1, k):
        if M[i, x] < min_val:
            min_val = M[i, x]
            min_ind = x
    return min_ind

@cuda.jit('void(int32[:,:], float32[:,:])')
def cuda_backtrack(backtrack, M):
    j = cuda.grid(1)
    if (j >= backtrack.shape[1]):
        return
    for i in range (1,backtrack.shape[0]):
        cuda.syncthreads()
        min_energy = 0
        if j == 0:
            idx = cuda_argmin(M, i-1, j, j+2)
            backtrack[i, j] = idx
            min_energy = M[i-1, idx]
        elif j == backtrack.shape[1]-1:
            idx = cuda_argmin(M, i-1, j-1, j+1)
            backtrack[i, j] = idx
            min_energy = M[i-1, idx]
        else:
            idx = cuda_argmin(M, i-1, j-1, j+2)
            backtrack[i, j] = idx
            min_energy = M[i-1, idx]
        M[i, j] += min_energy

def cuda_create_backtrack(img):
    r, c, _ = img.shape
    energy_map = calc_energy(img)
    print(energy_map)
    M = energy_map.copy()
    backtrack = np.zeros_like(M, dtype=np.int)
    #shape[1] must be less than 1025
    blockdim = backtrack.shape[1]
    griddim = 1
    cuda_backtrack[griddim, blockdim](backtrack, M)

    return M, backtrack

img = np.array([[[ 55,  53,  55],
              [ 81,  70,  64],
              [ 57,  51,  49],
              [ 50,  51,  55]],

             [[ 59,  56,  57],
              [189, 157, 142],
              [133, 104,  92],
              [ 34,  33,  35]],

             [[ 31,  32,  34],
              [174, 144, 131],
              [176, 145, 131],
              [ 18,  18,  20]],

             [[ 22,  23,  25],
              [ 80,  70,  66],
              [118, 104,  97],
              [ 14,  15,  17]]], dtype=np.uint8)

print("host backtrack")
M,backtrack = create_backtrack(img)
print(backtrack)
print(M)
print("GPU backtrack")
M,backtrack = cuda_create_backtrack(img)
print(backtrack)
print(M)
$ python t48.py
host backtrack
[[1750. 1622. 1752. 1176.]
 [1742. 1360. 1948. 1362.]
 [2078. 1772. 1690. 1674.]
 [1524. 2300. 2142. 1654.]]
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 3 3]
 [1 1 3 3]
 [1 2 3 3]]
[[1750. 1622. 1752. 1176.]
 [3364. 2982. 3124. 2538.]
 [5060. 4754. 4228. 4212.]
 [6278. 6528. 6354. 5866.]]
GPU backtrack
[[1750. 1622. 1752. 1176.]
 [1742. 1360. 1948. 1362.]
 [2078. 1772. 1690. 1674.]
 [1524. 2300. 2142. 1654.]]
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 3 3]
 [1 1 3 3]
 [1 2 3 3]]
[[1750. 1622. 1752. 1176.]
 [3364. 2982. 3124. 2538.]
 [5060. 4754. 4228. 4212.]
 [6278. 6528. 6354. 5866.]]
$
```

I'm not suggesting the above code is defect free or suitable for any particular purpose.  It is mostly your code, with a few items "fixed" to outline the issues I found.  In particular, some additional design work would be necessary if you wanted to extend this code beyond the 1-threadblock example given above (or images of width larger than 1024), as already discussed.